# expect script runs in shell but fails via cgi

Tags: bash, cgi, expect

im running a expect script which works perfectly fine when call it at the command line, but if i run the exact same command via cgi, it fails after the password and gives the following error

**Error opening terminal: unknown. Connection to 10.x.x.x closed. send: spawn id exp8 not open while executing "send -- "\r"" (file "./precheck.exp" line 24)**

the webserver is mongoose and it is running under my current user
any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What program are you spawning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI scripts are run by a daemon process (the web server) which has no TTY attached.  Password queries, however, are typically done on the attached TTY.  If a process actually *tests* for the existence of the TTY, if will find a difference between running in a user-called shell script and running as a CGI.

Now, what can you do to solve your problem?

You can either create and attach a PTY to your process in question, so that it finds a TTY even if it is run as a CGI script.  Or you can try to convince the program in question to get the password from somewhere else.  I would propose to try this way, if possible.  Slipping in a fake TTY just for *this* probably isn't easy and I would consider it a hack.

Telling a program that it's okay if there is no TTY and here you go, eat that password, that's a decent approach to your problem.

Comment: hi, thanks for this, i think i understand what you are saying, but i can't understand how do i work around this. i.e how do i tell a program that its ok if there is no tty. which program would i be telling here the webserver? or the ssh on the remote machine?

Comment: Depends on the program in question of course.  I don't know your expect script (as you didn't post it), so that would be wild guessing.  But often a program which tries to ask a password also has a way of getting the password via a command line option.

Comment: Alfe , thanks for everything, but the problem got solved by adding export TERM=xterm to the cgi file. thanks again.